# C# / nAudio - Sending a MIDI message to controller

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

I'm building my own custom midi mapping app, and so far so good. I've been using nAudio to recieve midi messages, and it's working like a charm.

But when wanting to send something back, I run into some trouble. To enable a light on my controller I gotta send a Note On message: 90 kk 01 for example, where kk equals the corresponding key. (see picture below)

[image]

However, it is not working. I'm not getting any error messages at all, but nothing is lighting up neither.

Example of what I'm sending:

```
midiOut = new MidiOut(MIDIInDevice);
 midiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StartNote(56, 1, 0).RawData);
```

56 is the Note, 1 the volume, and 0 the channel.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MIDIInDevice` an output device?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same device as where I'm getting input from

Comment: you are saying kk is the button number. Then what does 90 kk 7F means? And where does this message is generating from?

Answer (score 1):

Choose right channel and try to send **NoteOn** event.

```
var noteOnEvent = new NoteOnEvent(0L, channel, note, 127, 200);
midi.Send(noteOnEvent.GetAsShortMessage());
midi.Send(noteOnEvent.OffEvent.GetAsShortMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you posted says that the lights are controlled with Note On messages. I'm not familiar with the C# library, but I'm guessing `StopNote` sends a Note Off message. Try using the equivalent that sends a Note On message. (Perhaps `StartNote`?)

Comment: Oversight of me simplifying the code. I tried StartNote already, to no avail unfortunately. Thanks for pointing it out though, i'll make the edit

Comment: In that case, your message looks right. The next thing I would do is check to make sure the device is receiving what you think you're sending. On OS X I'd use [MIDIMonitor](https://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) to look at the MIDI commands coming out of my program. Hopefully there's something like that for Windows.

Comment: Just remembered I used [MIDI-OX](http://www.midiox.com) back in the early 21st century. Looks like it hasn't been updated since Vista but it might still work.

Comment: Got it, apparently midiOut = new MidiOut(MIDIInDevice); should have been midiOut = new MidiOut(MIDIInDevice+1); , now it works flawlessly